# how do I call the previous Node of an unknow object?

Tags: java, oop, linked-list, blockchain, doubly-linked-list

I am using custom made data structure and, in this project, I am using a doubly LinkedList to implement a blockchain.

so I have made a Main class and a Block class and of course the LinkedList class, the LinkedList class was made to accept data of the type Block so when I try to add elements to my list i pass on a new block with the information the problem is after the first element I don't know how to call the hash value of the previous block.

basically in every block class there should be a hash and the hash of the previous block in block one there is no prev hash so its 0 but the second block and onwards is where I am lost.

this is my block class

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Block {

    public String hash;
    public String previousHash;
    private String data;
    private long timeStamp;

    public Block(String data, String previousHash) {
        this.data = data;
        this.previousHash = previousHash;
        this.timeStamp = new Date().getTime();
        this.hash = calculateHash();
    }

    public String calculateHash() {
        String calculatehash = StringUtil.applySha256(
                previousHash + Long.toString(timeStamp) + data);

        return calculatehash;
    }
}
```

this is my doubly LinkedList file

```
class Node {

    private Block data; // node storing int data
    private Node nextNode; // the next pointer node, the arrow in drawing
    private Node prevNode;

    // don't forget the class constructor
    public Node(Block data2) {
        this.data = data2;
    }

    // since we made variable private
    // to access them we need setters and getters
    public Block getData() {
        return this.data;
    }

    public Node getNextNode() {
        return this.nextNode;
    }

    public Node getPrevNode() {
        return this.prevNode;
    }

    public Block setData(Block data) {
        return this.data = data;
    }

    public Node setNextNode(Node nextNode) {
        return this.nextNode = nextNode;
    }

    public Node setpervNode(Node prevNode) {
        return this.prevNode = prevNode;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Data: " + this.data;
    }

   
}

public class DoublyLinkedlist {

    private Node head;
    private Node tail;
    private int size = 0;


    public DoublyLinkedlist() {
        
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return this.size;
    }

    public void addFirst(Block data) {
        Node node = new Node(data);
        if (this.tail == null && this.head == null) {
            this.tail = node;
            this.head = node;
        } else if (this.head == null) {
            this.head = node;
        } else {
            Node old = this.head;
            node.setNextNode(old);
            this.head = node;
            old.setpervNode(this.head);
        }
        this.size++;
    }

    public void addLast(Block data) {
        Node node = new Node(data);
        if (this.tail == null && this.head == null) {
            this.tail = node;
            this.head = node;
        } else if (this.tail == null) {
            this.tail = node;
        } else {
            Node old = this.tail;
            this.tail.setNextNode(node);
            this.tail = node;
            this.tail.setpervNode(old);
        }
        this.size++;
    }

    public Node removeFirst() {
        Node removed = this.head;
        this.head = this.head.getNextNode();
        this.size--;
        return removed;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String output = "[size=" + this.size + "] >> ";
        Node fromHead = this.head;
        while (fromHead != null) {
            output = output + fromHead.getData();
            if (fromHead != this.tail)
                output = output + " >> ";
            fromHead = fromHead.getNextNode();
        }
        output += "\n";
        Node fromTail = this.tail;
        while (fromTail != null) {
            output = output + fromTail.getData();
            if (fromTail != this.head)
                output = output + " << ";
            fromTail = fromTail.getPrevNode();
        }
        return output;
    }

    public boolean contains(Block data) {
        Node current = this.head;
        while (current != null) {
            if (current.getData() == data) {
                return true;
            }
            current = current.getNextNode();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void clear() {
        while (this.head != null) {
            this.removeFirst();
        }
        System.out.println("List Is Cleared!");
    }
    
}
```

and this is my Main class

```
public class Main {

    public static DoublyLinkedlist blockchain = new DoublyLinkedlist();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        blockchain.addFirst(new Block("hi i am the first block", "0"));
        blockchain.addLast(new Block("yo i am the second block", blockchain.get(blockchain.getSize()-1.hash)));       
              
       
       


    }
}
```

i tried using the get method based on a tutorial that was implementing using an arraylist but obviously it's a wrong syntax.

Comment: when you use addlast you can use the hash of the tail as it will be the has of the previous for that new add block (make sure that blockchain has at least 1 block so tail do not be null) something i am not sure about when you addFirst that would require that you recalculate the whole hash and previous hash for each element unless you use add first for only the first element

Comment: Is there any part of your code that must absolutely stay the same, or is it all open for modification?

Answer (score 0):

The main program should not have to deal with retrieving hashes, not even with creating blocks. Instead aim for your main code to look like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static DoublyLinkedlist blockchain = new DoublyLinkedlist();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        blockchain.addLast("Hi, I am the first block");
        blockchain.addLast("Yo, I am the second block");       
    }
}
```

Then your other classes would also need some adaptations. In `Node` I would add a constructor that can take a second argument, so it can establish the link with a previous node:

```
    public Node(Block data, Node prevNode) { // Additional constructor
        this.data = data;
        this.prevNode = prevNode;
        if (prevNode != null) {
            prevNode.setNextNode(this);
        }
    }
```

In the `DoublyLinkedList` class, remove the `addFirst` method: you don't want to add blocks **before** any existing blocks, as that would invalidate the hashes of the blocks that are already in the list. Blocks should only be added at the end.

The `addLast` method should take a string instead of a `Block` instance, and this method can also be used for adding the very first block.

```
    public void addLast(String data) {
        tail = new Node(new Block(data, tail != null ? tail.getData().hash : "0"), tail);
        if (head == null) head = tail;
        size++;
    }
```

Comment: okay i understand the idea behind it but how can i set the previous hash of the first block as 0 ?

Comment: It's there in my answer's code? Do you see the "0"?

Comment: oh yeah sorry i didnt know u kept i t the addLast method thanks, but now i am having a problem with printing the list because its only printing the location from the block class i used a .toString but it didnt work

Comment: Is that a new question?

Comment: its a continuation

Comment: I don't see a problem. I added `System.out.println(blockchain.toString() );` to the main program, and it prints the two blocks as expected: both forward and backward. I suggest that if you have a new problem, you post a new question that focuses on that. Your question here is not about a `toString` implementation, so it is a new question, and the comment section is really not the place for follow-up questions. Can you post a new question about it?

Comment: okay understood

Comment: Having said that, you never call `toString` on the `Node` class. Just call it instead of `getData()`. But yes, this is a "problem" that is unrelated to your question at the top.

Comment: ...and you also need a `toString` method on `Block`, which needs to be called from `Node::toString`.